# eclipse: how to debug a Scala program called from a shell script

Tags: eclipse, scala, shell, debugging

I have a Scala program that is triggered from a shell script. I'd like to be able to run the program in eclipse in debug mode. Anybody knows how that can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you just specify the parameters in the run configuration in eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a run configuration for this yet, as I'm not sure how to set one up for this scenario. Let's say there is a Hello World Scala program and and a shell script that calls it. I want to be able to put a breakpoint at the print hello world line and have the control stop at that line when the shell script is executed.

Comment: So you want to see what's going on in your shell script before it calls your scala program?

Comment: It would be great if I can do that too along with debugging the Scala program. But I'm more interested in the Scala program itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to debug both together, but what you can do is run your script with the option -xv.  So...

```
user@mypc$: bash -xv myscript other_args
```

That will show you the commands that are executed along with their parameters.

Then in Eclipse you can debug your Scala program normally and pass those parameters to it through the main method or run configuration.

Typically debuggers are language specific and won't be able to do both bash scripts and code in another language, but with this method, you should be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This was very helpful. And a generic solution, not limited to Scala.